# Vue component prop not updating on $emit

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I need to update the component's prop on every route change but it stays with the last info given.

For example, I fill the form in RouteTwo, with id, name, lastname and phone, and if I change to RouteOne, ComponentOne stays with those four values (including phone) until I start filling the form in RouteOne.

I'm working with vue 2.6.12, vue-router 3.4.9

Here's an example code:

General.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <router-view @data-updated="updateFunction"></router-view>
        </div>
        <div>
            <component-one v-bind:component-prop="reactiveProp" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import ComponentOne from './ComponentOne.vue';
export default {
    components: {
        ComponentOne,
    },
    data: () => ({
        reactiveProp
    }),
    methods: {
        updateFunction(value) {
            this.reactiveProp = value;
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

ComponentOne.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{ componentProp.id }}</p>
        <p>{{ componentProp.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ componentProp.lastname }}</p>
        <p v-if="routePath == 'routetwo'">{{ componentProp.phone }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        componentProp: Object,
    },
    data: () => ({
        routePath: ''
    }),
    mounted() {
        this.routePath = this.$route.path.split('/').at(-1);
    },
}
</script>
```

RouteOne.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="dataObject.id" />
        <input type="text" v-model="dataObject.name" />
        <input type="text" v-model="dataObject.lastname" />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        dataObject: {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            lastname: '',
        },
    }),
    methods: {
        // some logic methods
    },
    watch: {
        dataObject: {
            handler: function() {
                this.$emit('data-updated',this.dataObject);
            },
            deep: true,
        }
    },
}
</scipt>
```

RouteTwo.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="dataObject.id" />
        <input type="text" v-model="dataObject.name" />
        <input type="text" v-model="dataObject.lastname" />
        <input type="text" v-model="dataObject.phone" />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        dataObject: {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            lastname: '',
            phone: '',
        },
    }),
    methods: {
        // some logic methods
    },
    watch: {
        dataObject: {
            handler: function() {
                this.$emit('data-updated',this.dataObject);
            },
            deep: true,
        }
    },
}
</scipt>
```

Router

```
{
    name: 'general',
    path: '/general',
    component: () => import('General.vue'),
    children: [
        {
            name: 'route-one',
            path: 'routeone',
            component: () => import('RouteOne.vue')
        },
        {
            name: 'route-two',
            path: 'routetwo',
            component: () => import('RouteTwo.vue')
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you see in your Vue devtools?

Comment: The only thing that needs to be fixed seems to be `immediate: true` in a watcher

Comment: @kissu I see the component and the props changing, but in the DOM it stays the same

Comment: @EstusFlask Tried your recommendation but the problem continues.

Comment: @W.S. sorry. I'm editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Switching routes doesn't cause a change in `dataObject`, so no emit will fire.  Technically, switching routes causes one route component to be unmounted (destroyed), and the next route component to be created, meaning `dataObject` is created/recreated every time you switch back and forth, which is fundamentally different from `dataObject` being "changed" (which activates the watcher).

Instead, put a watcher on the route itself in the General component and reset `reactiveProp` when that watcher activates.  This will clear the fields when going between RouteOne and RouteTwo:

```js
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      this.reactiveProp = {};
    },
  },
```